# powershell loop to continous check if server is up

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I want to run a script to check if 5 servers are up and running based on a specific service is running.If that service is running then we know that server is up and accesible. If it does not reply with a response back then I want it to continously check for it. Heres what I got so far:

```
Get-Service LANMANSERVER -ComputerName JOHNJ1
Get-Service LANMANSERVER -ComputerName JOHNJ2
Get-Service LANMANSERVER -ComputerName JOHND1
Get-Service LANMANSERVER -ComputerName JOHNM
Get-Service LANMANSERVER -ComputerName JOHNI
start-sleep 90
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yep you just need to check the `Status` property on the returned object like this:

```
$servers = "JOHNJ1", "JOHNJ2"
foreach ($server in $servers) {
    $status = (get-service -Name lanmanserver -ComputerName $server).Status
    if ($status -eq "Running") {
        "Its Up!"
    } else {
        "Its Down!"
    }
}
```

**Update** Here is an example of how to wait for a server to become online:

```
$servers = "JOHNJ1", "JOHNJ2"
foreach ($server in $servers) {
    while ( (get-service -Name lanmanserver -ComputerName $server).Status -ne "Running" ) {
        "Waiting for $server ..."
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
    }
    "$server is Up!"
}
```

Comment: Thanks would I need a while loop to continously check until that server was up based on it checkign for that service?

Comment: @BigCAT41 Yep, I added an example of how to do that.

Comment: $servers     = "JOHNJ01", "JOHNJ02", "JOHNI01", "JOHN01", "JOHND01";   
foreach ($server in $servers) {
    $status = (get-service -Name spooler -ComputerName $server).Status
 $server
 if ($status -eq "Running") {
        "Its Up!"
    } 
 else {
        "Its Down!" 
 
foreach ($server in $servers) {
  
   while ( (get-service -Name spooler -ComputerName $server).Status -ne "Running" ) {
        "Waiting for $server ..."
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
    }
    "$server is Up!"
}

    }
}
 start-sleep 90

Comment: @BigCAT41 Glad it helped. If you found this answered your question please mark it as the accepted answer. Thank you.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid the red error messages: get-service : Cannot find any service with service name 'lanmanserver'.
At D:\scripts\ServerMonitor.ps1:3 char:16
+     $status = (get-service -Name lanmanserver -ComputerName $server).Status
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (lanmanserver:String) [Get-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoServiceFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetServiceCommand

Comment: @NealWalters You could do -- `$service = Get-Service ... -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` and then -- `if ($service) { ... }`.